# I'm trying to add a for loop that loops from min to max and I came across this error. How do I loop them together in python?

Tags: python, for-loop, integer

for inches in min and max(1, 11):
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

Comment: you've got a variable called `max` although thats likely only one issue here

Comment: Do you mean `for inches in range(1, 11)`? Note that the end of a range is exclusive, so you will start iterating at 1, and end with 10, not including 11.

Answer (score -1):

max(1, 11) -will return you the maximum that is 11.

its a type int int not iterable

you can loop in range [min,max) :

```
for inches in range(1, 11):
```

Comment: "you can do loop if its not iterable"?